# How to add something to a list but first check to see if it already exists

Tags: python, list

So I have a list named clues which consists of letter and symbol pairings which the user can add to... However before the user adds a new symbol and letter pairing to the list, I want the program to check to see whether this pairing already exists in clues. If it does then a message saying " This pairing already exists, please try again ".

This is my code for this section so far...

```
#PROCEDURE FOR ADDING A NEW PAIRING
def add_pairing(clues):
addClue = False
#USER INPUTS A LETTER AND SYMBOL
letter=input("What letter would you like to add?  ").upper()

symbol=input("\nWhat symbol would you like to pair with  ").upper()
userInput= letter + symbol
#GOES THROUGH CLUES TO SEE IF THE PAIRING HAS ALREADY BEEN ENTERED
for clue in clues:
#IF THE CLUE HAS ALREADY BEEN ADDED, IT WILL PRINT A MESSAGE        
    if letter in clues:
        print("The letter either doesn't exist or has already been entered ")
        break
    elif symbol in clues:
        print("The letter either doesn't exist or has already been entered")

    elif len(userInput) ==1:
        print("You can only enter one character")

#IF THE CLUE DOESN'T EXIST IN CLUES, IT WILL GO TO THE else STATEMENT       
    else:
        newClue = letter + symbol
        addClue = True
if addClue == True:
    clues.append(newClue)
    #PRINTS MESSAGE SAYING THAT THE PAIRING HAS BEEN ADDED
    print("The pairing has been added")
#PRINTS CLUES AFTER THE PAIRING HAS BEEN ADDED
    print (clues)
return clues
```

Comment: What issues are you having?

Comment: Have you tried `newClue in clues` or `clues = set()`?

Comment: Sorry Roger Fan I should have added that into the description...

Comment: The issue I am having is that it is adding a pairing to the list even though the pairing still exists....

Comment: matsjoyce - What do you mean? Should I  replace the clues in if letter in clues with newClues?

Comment: A letter can have multiple symbols paired with it? What is a 'symbol' anyway? Do you need to look up by letter later? Waht format is the incoming 'clues'?

Comment: SO an example would be like this... What letter would you like me to add? I What symbol would you like me to add? * I* Has now been added to the list of clues... Clues are now I*

Comment: But obviously if the user enters the letter I and symbol * again, then an error message should occur because it already exists in the list of clues...

Comment: What if he adds `I+` afet `I*`? Its a unique pairing. Does that go in? Or he adds `ITHISISNOTASYMBOL`. Does that go in?

Comment: I should have mentioned that, yes if the letter matches like above then the error message should still get printed... Same with the symbol as well !

Answer (score 2):

You're checking `if letter in clues` and `elif symbol in clues:` where what you want is `in clue`, without the s. Otherwise, why loop?

That's the reason you're seeing dups. There are many other issues there, though, such as:

- Iterating through the list each time is costly (O(n)). Use a set for letters and a set for symbols, and the check becomes O(1). If the "clues" have any relation between them - implement that - either with a dictionary or some other structure - but concatenating them and throwing them into a list seems like the least suitable solution.
- You're writing `userInput= letter + symbol` and then `elif len(userInput) ==1:`. This is the wrong check - if the user inputs more than one character its len would be more than 2, not 1.
- Why check that inside the loop, anyways? One check is enough.
- Why `break` in `if letter in clues:` and not in `elif symbol in clues:`?

Comment: What are the other issues?

Comment: @user3633316 added some.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is the ideal object for pairs of values like this:

```
clues = dict()
while True:
    letter = input("What letter would you like to add?  ").upper()
    if letter == "":
        break        
    symbol = input("\nWhat symbol would you like to pair with  ").upper()

    if letter not in clues.keys() and symbol not in clues.values():
        clues[letter]=symbol
    else:
        print("Letter or symbol already paired")

print(clues)
```

Comment: `clues.update({letter:symbol})` is a convoluted way to say `clues[letter]=symbol`. And since you never add symbol as a key, `symbol not in clues` won't find them.

Comment: OK thanks for this, is there I can do this in a list?

Comment: @tdelaney I find it (slightly) more logical though it's down to personal preference. And I was under the impression that 'in' included both keys and values. Updated

Comment: no, 'in' is just keys. And your implementation is making a lot of assumptions. Notice that OP is adding `letter+symbol` to the list. So its something like `KSOMESYMBOL`. I assume that `KSOMEOTHERSYMBOL` would be unique and added also.

Comment: Absolutely. I was simply demonstrating the use of a dictionary for the job. OP can make situation specific alterations

Comment: When I try using the code provided above, it keeps looping. I have tried debugging but I can't seem to find any issues... This is what is happening... `What letter would you like to add?  r

What symbol would you like to pair with  $
What letter would you like to add?  r

What symbol would you like to pair with  %
Letter or symbol already paired
What letter would you like to add?`